# How to use integer from one command into another?

Tags: macros, expl3, input, programming, variable

I have following way to get number of spaces in a string

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\HowManySpaces}{ m }{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #1 }
  \int_eval:n {(\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq) - 1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now I want to use output of this command as input some where else, e.g. `aaa \kern{\HowManySpaces{a b c}pt bbb`. This use of output may not be restricted to `kern`, I want to define if-else commands (which I already have) according to the number of spaces in the string (I know how to use `\ifnum\value{}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the command to be expandable, so you can't perform assignments inside the definition. Note that expandable commands are marked with a star in `interface3`.

The following should work (it also trims leading and trailing spaces):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count_spaces:n { e }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \HowManySpaces { m } { 
  \str_count_spaces:e { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

aaa\kern\HowManySpaces{a b c}pt bbb

\ifnum\HowManySpaces{a b c}=2 correct \else incorrect \fi
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. Do you know any good references to learn expl3 or latex3e coding? I want to understand how you have coded it.